# Create non-aggregated horizontal table from vertical data (using records in a column as headers) for Access 2007 SQL

Tags: ms-access

Before anyone asks, yes I have searched this problem to the nth degree and can't get the results I need in Access 2007 syntax. All the solutions seem sound but it keeps coming down to syntax errors. Is there different syntax for MS SQL versus native SQL?

## So here is my data :

TABLE       TRXCODE    TRXINFO

20141002    RES 9[57]

20141002    TRM AWCORD01

20141002    MRC ddfhrhamwss

20141002    RES 1[49]

20141002    TRM AWTERC01

20141002    MRC ftttyyxxdsj3

20141002    RES 1[49]

20141002    TRM AWTERC01

20141002    MRC 5556jdjsjsjd

## And this is what I'm trying to produce

TABLE       RES     TRM         MRC

20141002    9[57]   AWCORD01    ddfhrhamwss

20141002    1[49]   AWTERC01    ftttyyxxdsj3

20141002    1[49]   AWTERC01    5556jdjsjsjd

Very similar to the PIVOT function but I can't have aggregation.  There are thousands of rows but only 3 TRXCODEs that I need as column headings. My columns would read TABLE, RES, TRM and MRC. The TRXINFO would then fall under each of the column headings

Short of losing my mind on syntax and aggregation I would really appreciate a solution. I hope I have also explained my problem ad result clearly.

Cheers
Gage

Comment: Are there always the three TRXCodes for each [Table]. If so you can do this with a couple of inner joins.

Comment: There is a total of 6 TRXCodes.

Comment: Okay starter for ten, coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select r.TABLE,r.TRXINFO as 'RES', t.TRXINFO as 'TRM', m.TRXINFO as 'MRC'
From MyTable r
Left Join MyTable t On r.Table = t.table and t.TRXCODE = 'TRM' 
Left Join MyTable m On m.Table = t.table and m.TRXCODE = 'MRC'
Where r.TRXCODE = 'RES'
```

Add more joins for the other codes, an index or two if you don't have them will no doubt give a useful performance improvement.

This is basically the old school way to do pivot type queries before pivot was added as a feature.

If there might not be a 'RES' record you have a bit more work
If you know there is always one particular TRXCODE, then just use it instead of 'RES'

Full Outer Join (or equivalent, though that would be painful with five joins).

Or there's a sneaky Pete solution, where you basically first create a query like

```
Select Distinct [Table], 'XXX' as 'TRXCODE', 'Do Not Care' as TRXINFO
From MyTable
```

Then join your six codes to that, then query from that to drop the XXX column.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help but it's still syntax errors. I'm starting to think my Access is corrupt.